# Observing arrangedObjects from NSOutlineController

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview

`NSArrayController`'s `arrangedObjects` property returns an array containing the objects being controlled. This array is observable, so I can do this:

```
[_myArrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.myProperty" options:0 context:myContext];
```

Any time the myProperty property of any of the objects in the controller is modified, I'm told about it.

Now I need to do exactly the same thing using an `NSOutlineView`. However, `NSOutlineView`'s `arrangedObjects` property returns an array of NSTreeNodes, so I need to do something like this:

```
[_myArrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.representedObject.myProperty" options:0 context:myContext];
```

But that's not allowed since representedObject isn't KVC compliant.

Is there an easy way to do what I need?

Comment: I thought NSTreeController's arrangedObjects returned a single proxy root node, so would arrangedObjects.childNodes.representedObject.myProperty work?  Even if you have several top level nodes, you'd get to them through arrangedObjects.childNodes as far as I'm aware.

Comment: That's true, but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that using simply "arrangedObjects.myProperty" works!